# How do i get this loop to stop correctly and show the sum of prices?

Tags: javascript

```
var sum = 0;
var Discount = 0;
var afterDiscount = 0;
var Price;
while (true) {
    Price = (prompt("Please enter a Price or -1 to STOP"));
    if (Price === -1)
    sum=sum+Price;
if (Price <= 50) {
            alert(Price);
        } else if (Price > 50 && Price <= 100) {
            alert(Price-Price*.10);

        } else if (Price > 100) {
            alert(Price-Price*.20);

        }
}
alert(sum);
```

I need to know how to get the loop to stop correctly and get the sum to output as an Alert

Comment: Why do you need while loop? It does nothing...

Answer (score 1):

You can (and most likely will have to) use `break;` to get out of the loop.
Like:

```
if (price == -1) {
  break;
}
```

Comment: thank you it helped i got the break to work =] just need to get sum to output correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can prompt without the loop. Remove the `while` entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is an infinite loop:

```
while (true) {
    ...
}
```

You can break out of the loop when you get -1; consider the following:

```
if (Price === -1){
    break;
}
```

Once you have exited the loop, you can now handle your `sum` however you wish. In your example, you do this:

```
alert(sum);
```

This will now work as intended after your loop has exited.

**Note:**

For your `sum` to correctly increase its value, don't forget to cast your `prompt` result to an `int`, since `prompt` always returns a `string`. Consider the following fix:

```
Price = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a Price or -1 to STOP"));
        ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Awesome so i got the break to work now can you tell me how i could possibly alert after the loop to show sum of final costs?

Comment: @Toteeto The same way you have it as before should work. After the loop exits, your `alert(sum)` should fire - see my updated answer.

Comment: I tried it keeps just giving me my input values like if i enter "45,105,65" it spits out 04510565

Comment: @Toteeto That is because `prompt` always returns a string, so your code `sum = sum + Price` is concatenating as a string - see my updated answer.

Comment: @Toteeto Glad I could help!

Comment: one more quick question If i input what my instructors numbers "50,100,200" after the discounts the sum should be 300 but im getting  350 any ideas

Comment: @Toteeto That is because you're not actually applying the discount in your code - I'm not going to do it for you, but look carefully at your code and make sure to add to the `sum` correctly in the right places. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

var sum   = 0,
    Price = 0,
    loop  = true;

while ( loop ) {
    console.log( 'Suma: ' + sum );

    Price = (prompt( "Please enter a Price or -1 to STOP" ));


    if ( Price == -1 ) {
        //sum--;
        loop = false;

    } else {
        sum = sum + Number(Price);
    }


    if (Price <= 50) {
        alert(Price);

    } else if (Price > 50 && Price <= 100) {
        alert(Price-Price*.10);

    } else if (Price > 100) {
        alert(Price-Price*.20);

    }
}

alert(sum);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that still yields 350 which is the sum of just base input not after the discount but I appreciate the answer dude